# Moment JS but for Salesforce Apex

Tags: date, datetime, formatting, open-source

Are there any open source libraries similar to Moment JS but for Apex?

Reference:

- [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: If you don't find a suitable alternative, I'd like to have a conversation with you about including something like this in my (hopefully-soon-to-be-released) open-source library. What features are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @sfdcfox I developed an Apex wrapper class called "Chrono" which helps with a specific use case: Creating and displaying a date/time in Visualforce from the perspective of a TimeZone that is neither the user's nor UTC. Would need my company's permission to share it but maybe this could be a useful starting point?

Comment: @sfdcfox usually it's features that relate to displaying: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ ... But having used Moment JS a fair amount, the richness of the library is truly impressive, a similar library for Apex would be **very** useful and I'd imagine adopted by many!

Comment: Okay, but how does this differentiate from using DateTime.format?

Comment: `DateTime.format` cannot, for one, produce non-English month or day names. And it is limited to only two time zone options, local or GMT.

Comment: Today I was battling with `Date` so I had to jump through hoops and make my code less concise... I find working with Date and DateTime in Apex much more fiddly than in `C#` or in `JavaScript` using `Moment JS`... perhaps it's because I don't have 10+ years experience with Apex like you... but I am reasonably sure it's because the Apex language isn't as mature and full of the richess other languages have...

Comment: @sfdcfox what's the ETA of your (hopefully-soon-to-be-released) open-source library? :)

Comment: @Robs I don't have an ETA (probably why it's taken so long to be released, I haven't forced myself to set a date), but I feel I'll probably be ready to release it soon, at least in some beta form. It has some pretty cool stuff like `Long.parseLong(String value, Integer radix)`, but it's still an incredibly small library. It needs more work.